# Make a test server not accessible to any networks

Tags: apache, testing, lamp

I need to make a test lamp server that runs php files on localhost for anyone with direct access to the computer but isn't accessible from any networks. How does one do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Apache, you can simply make it listen only to 127.0.0.1 using the following directive:

```
 Listen 127.0.0.1:80
```

Answer (score 1):

In Apache conf (httpd.conf) you can configure it so it only listens on your local ip (127.0.0.1). I can't remember where in the conf, but I think it's the same place you configure the port, i.e. it's normally something like:

```
*:80
```

Change it to:

```
127.0.0.1:80
```